# График во времени с учетом отсутствующих данных

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Такая задача: в первом столбце указана дата, во втором - значение некоторой переменной. Нужно добавить на страницу график значений этой переменной во времени. Но есть нюанс. Значения имеют "дыры" во времени, а не даны на каждый день. То есть, например:

```
|   Дата   | Значение |
|01.03.2019|    44    |
|05.03.2019|    68    |
|25.03.2019|    99    |
|01.04.2019|    73    |
|16.04.2019|    82    |
```

Если просто добавить график и указать этот диапазон, то он расположит столбцы со значением подряд (5 столбцов без промежутков). Но так нельзя понять, как далеко во времени значения друг от друга на календаре. Нужно чтобы в графике оставались в худшем случае пустоты за то время, которое не указано между имеющимися значениями, а в лучшем - интерполировать соседние значения для получения плавного графика. Вариант с построением нового массива данных, в первом столбце которого будут все даты (и те, что отсутствуют в первом), в который подтягиваются данные из первого массива в соответствующие по дате строки - не рассматривается. Нужно работать именно с нашим не полным массивом.

Не смог найти корректного способа добавить график, который знает что такое время и отображает значения именно во времени, а не просто подставляет даты в горизонтальную ось как значения.

Пример того, как НЕ должен выглядеть график (между датами есть разрыв, но на графике они идут подряд):

[image: Пример того как НЕ должен выглядеть график]

Comment: Я вижу столбчатую диаграмму, а не график... если сделать именно график - всё будет прекрасно видно.

Comment: @Akina никак нет. Обновил картинку для наглядности.

Comment: [Скриншот](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1o3QY.png) графика - всё нормально, даты воспринимаются именно как даты, а не как наименования.

Comment: @Akina Есть анекдот. Звонит мужик в скорую, и говорит: "Доктор, спасите! У меня открытый перелом, кровь хлещет!". А доктор внимательно изучил что-то: "Ну что вы, голубчик! Я всё проверил, моя нога полностью исправна!" Очевидно, мой скрин тоже из googlesheets, даты - в формате даты, а не текста, но отображается не корректно. Вот в том и вопрос ведь по сути: "Как добавить корректно?", а не "Возможно ли это?"

Comment: @Akina я разобрался сам, но спасибо за интерес. Ответ добавил в ответ.

Comment: o_O А ведь это Вы руками, явно, указали - по умолчанию эта опция выключена.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы график отображался корректно, нужно:

1. Дважды кликнуть на него
2. Перейти во вкладку Customize
3. Открыть подменю Horizontal Axis
4. Снять галочку "Treat labels as text"